# Transferring Gameboy Files From Phone To Computer

Tags: emulation, windows-10, game-boy-advance

I am currently playing Pokémon Emerald on my Android phone using My Boy (Free). So, I've made it quite far, and I am trying to transfer my game from my phone to my computer, where I would play it using VBA-M. (It's worth noting, I have a very limited knowledge of computers, so bear with me.)

Anyway, I save the game after playing it, both through the game itself and by clicking the little thing in the top center of the screen. I went into my downloads app, and grabbed the file (I think a zip) and uploaded it to my google drive. I downloaded it onto the computer, and started playing it on VBA-M. Then I noticed the problem. My save file didn't show up. Only a bar saying Options and one saying New Game popped up, my previous game didn't.

Does anyone know how I could fix this problem? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

it's really quite easy to transfer your saved files from phone to pc and back. I plan on making a short tutorial video on how to do so since I've managed to get it down to a T, doing it in just 3 minutes even WITHOUT a cable to connect the my device to the pc.

One thing to note, you might wanna get a hold of the latest version of basic VisualBoyAdvance for your comp instead of another version like VBA-M if you're not so computer savvy. other versions are built with specific purposes and tend to have more advanced options but that's entirely up to you and should still work with these instructions.

To transfer *from* your phone:

1. Simply save whatever game playing from **within the game**, (not save state as that can only be read by your phone's emulator) saving the game creates a '.sav' file on your phone with the name of that game attached. 
   (.sav is your general standard of flash memory save game files for Game Boy and related Nintendo emulators.)
2. Locate the .sav file on your phone. You can do this either on the computer after connecting your device, or through your 'file manager' app (maybe called 'files' on some phones). 
   Whether on your SD card or your phone storage, it's typically found in the \MyBoy\ folder. In your case, the file should look something like "Pokemon Ruby.sav"
3. Transfer it to pc. I normally just select it, hit share, and upload it to my Google Drive to carry it over (mostly cause my phone isn't very FTP friendly), but in your case, you can plug you're phone cable into the computer and refer back to step 2. find the .sav file through your pc. Go ahead and place it on the Desktop or anywhere you'll be able to find it.
4. Get it on VisualBoyAdvance. Open VBA and load your game (make sure it's the same .zip or .gba game file used on your phone). When the game is loaded, go to Options > Emulator > save type, and be sure the box next to "automatic" is checked. Then go to File > Import, and find your .sav file, (on the desktop or where you put it) and the game will restart with you're file from the phone.

Hope this helps you! I'll be sure to post my video here when I ever get around to it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 4/5 Copy the emulator!!! and then through the vba emulator load the game .sav file which you copied/moved from my boy to pc. If you've played  game(s) prior or not vba throws an error and says it will restart all... It'll be OK on a copy! The game .sav transfer will load. Save via emulator and we got easy transfers. Ty all here

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How is this answer starting from (and ending in) step 4/5? where did step 1-3 and step 5 go?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I installed on my phone My Boy Full, started to play Pokemon Ruby and then saved the game. Then I moved that saved file from my phone to my computer, just to notice that the save file extension is .st# where # is a number according with the save slot. Now, I use Visual Boy Advance 1.8.0-beta 3 and the save file extension is .sgm. So that has to be your problem, you can't load your phone save onto your computer's emulator cause save types are different. Hope this helps